# Yii ajax callback

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a dependent dropdown which I fill through ajax. I want to call a function after ajax is done. How can I do this?

```
echo Chtml::dropDownList('optAudioSura', $strAudioSuraTemp, $suraOptions,
                            array(
                                'ajax' => array(
                                    'type'=>'POST', //request type
                                    'url'=>CController::createUrl('QuText/audioFiles'), //url to call.
                                    'update'=>'#optAudio', 
                                    'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).serialize()',
                                    )
                                ));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a success function to the ajax, e.g.:

```
echo Chtml::dropDownList('optAudioSura', $strAudioSuraTemp, $suraOptions,
                        array(
                            'ajax' => array(
                                'type'=>'POST', //request type
                                'url'=>CController::createUrl('QuText/audioFiles'), //url to call.
                                'update'=>'#optAudio', 
                                'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).serialize()',
                                'success'=>'function(data) {
                                               // function code here
                                           }',
                                )
                            ));
```